# Unable to force window suppression when using TopologyTestDriver

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Topology in question:

```
builder.<String, String>stream(someTopic)
            .filter((k, v) -> !k.equals("heartbeat"))
            .filter((k, v) -> v != null)
            .filter(this::isRedactedInstance)
            // update our current cache of "known" redacted records
            .peek(this::updateRedactedCache)
            // change key so we can properly do the join further down
            .selectKey(this::getKeyFromRedacted)
            // now we slice the stream into 10 sec long slices and aggregate by key
            // Our redacted comes in every 10 seconds, so we should never get more than one set of redacted per cluster
            .groupByKey(Grouped.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.String()))
            .windowedBy(TimeWindows.of(Duration.ofSeconds(10)).advanceBy(Duration.ofSeconds(10)).grace(Duration.ofSeconds(3)))
            .aggregate(() -> null, this::aggregateRedactedByKey)
            // the suppress allows us to ignore intermediate records and only get the final 10 second worth aggregation
            .suppress(Suppressed.untilWindowCloses(Suppressed.BufferConfig.unbounded()))
            .toStream()
            .peek(this::deleteme)
```

The unit test being used to test is:

```
TopologyTestDriver driver = new TopologyTestDriver(redacted.getMainTopology(), streamingProperties);
driver.pipeInput(
    redactedRecordFactory.create(REDACTED_TOPIC,getRedactedKey(inst1), 
    getEntityEventString(inst1, instSeed1), 0L));
driver.pipeInput(
    redactedRecordFactory.create(REDACTED_TOPIC,getRedactedKey(inst2), 
    getEntityEventString(inst1, instSeed1), 1L));
driver.pipeInput(
    redactedRecordFactory.create(REDACTED_TOPIC,getRedactedKey(inst3), 
    getEntityEventString(inst3, instSeed3), Duration.ofDays(5).toMillis()));
```

1) When I run the test in debug mode, with a breakpoint at the "deleteMe" method, it is never hit.

2) When I add breakpoints in the "aggregate" method, they are hit as expected (thrice)

3) If I step through the test slowly enough, I *do* hit the breakpoint in the "deleteMe" method.

I have tried advancing the wallclock, but I understand that's not relevant to window suppression (and it didn't work besides).

I'm not sure what else to try - I would have expected the third event, with a super long timestamp, to have triggered the suppression.

Comment: I try to run your Topology and it un-suppress the first 2 event as expected, how do you do this `If I step through the test slowly enough`?

Comment: `suppress()` works based on event-time. Thus, advancing wall-clock time will not help. Maybe https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/streams/src/test/java/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/internals/SuppressScenarioTest.java helps -- it the Apache Kafka test that verifies that `suppress()` works correctly using the `TopologyTestDriver`